# How to restart Kubernetes-Engine Pods in a Python script

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gunicorn

I'm looking for a way to restart all the pods of my service. They should restart one by one so the service is always available. The restart should happen when a Python script from a different service is done.

I'm doing this because on the pods I want to restart there is a Gunicorn-server running which needs to reload some data. That only works when the server gets restarted.

The gunicorn service gets started in a Dockerfile:

```
CMD gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py -b :$PORT --preload app:app
```

But I'm guessing this is not too relevant.

I imagine the solution to be some kind of kubectl command that I can run in the Python script or a hint for a kubectl endpoint, that I couldn't find.

Comment: Can you add more details about how pods are created? i.e., are they created through a Pod spec or through a Deployment (or ReplicaSet) spec?

Comment: also, the answer will likely be a `kubectl` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kubectl rollout restart` has landed in Kubernetes v1.15 [1]. This feature is designed for exactly what you are looking to do - a rolling restart of pods.

[1] https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13488

Comment: Is there a way to run this from a different pod from the same cluster? Or is this out of the scope of a pod.

Comment: that's possible - as long as the service account invoking the command has permissions to do so